# How to exclude empty directories from zipfileset

Tags: ant, fileset

I have an ant target for creating zip like this -

```
<zip destfile="${dist}/myzip.zip">
    <zipfileset prefix="product/install" includes="docs/resources/**,docs/*.*" excludes="docs/build.bat,docs/*.xml,docs/resources/*.html"/>
</zip>
```

Now, how do I ensure that empty directories don't get included in this zipfileset.

Eg: docs/resources directory only has html files, all of which I have excluded above. How do I make sure docs/resources folder doesn't get included.

Should I be checking for this manually everytime? or is there an option like includeEmptyDirs="false"?

Answer (score 3):

I think there isn't an option for this in `zip` task, see [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html).

But what you can do is to make a copy with excludes/includes, and define to exclude the empty directories and then call the `zip` task on the copied folder:

```
<copy todir="tmp2" includeEmptyDirs="false">
    <fileset dir="tmp1" excludes="**/*.txt"/>
</copy>
<zip>...
```

[Documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) of `copy`